# How to send message from popup.js to content-script.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sendmessage

I have a button inside the popup.js which executes the content-script.js when the user clicks on the button. But every time I try to set it up, I get error messages saying **could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.**

**Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of runtime.sendMessage(optional string extensionId, any message, optional object options, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'options': Unexpected property: 'hello'.**

Or getting this error when using runtime over tabs in the sendMessage method.****

```
html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="startRecording" class="testbtn">Record</button>
  <!-- <button id="stopRecording" class="teststop">Stop</button> -->
   <script src="./popup.js" type="module"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

```
popup.js
const textBtn = document.querySelector('.testbtn');

textBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabsw) {
        const currentTabId = tabsw[0].id;
        console.log("Current tab ID is: " + currentTabId);
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            files: ["content.js"],
            target: {tabId: currentTabId}
          }, function () {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(currentTabId, { hello: "startRecording", duration: 60, quality: "720p" });
          });
        
      });
})
```

```
content.js
const overlayButton = document.createElement("button");
  overlayButton.innerText = "test";

  overlayButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (message.hello === "startRecording") {
            console.log(message);
}
        return true; // Needed to send a response asynchronously
      });

})

  document.body.appendChild(overlayButton);
```

```
manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Recorder Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Description of my extension",
    "permissions": ["scripting", "activeTab", "tabs", "tabCapture"],
    "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "Click Me"
       
    },
    
      "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
      },
      "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
    
  }
```

Comment: You probably look at an old error because it says "runtime.sendMessage" whereas you use "tabs.sendMessage" now. Click the delete icon or Clear all button to remove it. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I basically tried both, runtime and tabs, still getting these errors

Comment: @Yogi, When I use .tabs, it gives out first error and when I use .runtime, it gives out the second

Comment: Your onMessage listener registration doesn't run until the user clicks inside the page, so when you send a message there's no one to receive it. Use chrome.tabs.sendMessage and move onMessage listener registration outside the click listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Sure, so basically I am trying to setup tabCapture api in order to capture the whole tab recording, but I tried to use the tabCapture in the background.js and content.js but getting this error :- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'capture')
even though I had tabCapture permission in the manifest, I am not able to solve this issue

Comment: @wOxxOm I am really sorry to ping, could you please help me with this problem :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75742736/video-not-playing-after-the-tabcapture