# Video not playing after the tabCapture

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, media-player

I have a **popup.js, content.js, and background.js** in order to create an extension that would record the tab after the user clicks on the `record` button in the `popup.js`. The tabCapture API is registered inside the popup.js file which will then send a `Blob URL` for the recorded video to the `content.js` which would then use a `video` attribute and put the URL inside that src.
When I test the code in the browser, i.e. I clicked on the `record` button in the `popup.js`, it started capturing the current tab of the browser and then stop the recording after the three-second recording finished with the help of setTimout, I get a URL and then pass it to `content.js` and put it inside a video src and append the whole video attribute in the body of the document, but the video player is just showing a black thumbnail and nothing is playing inside it

```js
popup.js
textBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

                    chrome.tabCapture.capture({ video: true, audio: true }, (stream) => {
                      const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
                      const chunks = [];
                      recorder.start();
                      recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
                        chunks.push(event.data);
                      };
                
                      setTimeout(() => {
                        recorder.stop();
                        stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
                        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "video/webm" });
                        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                        //sendResponse({ url, type: "video/webm" });
                        console.log('please god');
                        console.log(url);

                        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabsw) {
                            const currentTabId = tabsw[0].id;
                            console.log("Current tab ID is: " + currentTabId);
                            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                                files: ["content.js"],
                                target: {tabId: currentTabId}
                              }, function () {
                                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(currentTabId, { url, type: "video/webm" });
                              });
                            
                          });

                      }, 3 * 1000);
                
                      
                      console.log(chunks);
                      
                    });
    
    
})
```

```js
content.js
const overlayButton = document.createElement("button");
  overlayButton.innerText = "test";

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.url && message.type === "video/webm") {
        overlayButton.addEventListener('click', function() {  
            alert('good');
          const video = document.createElement("video");
          video.src = message.url;
          video.controls = true;
          video.style.position = "fixed";
          video.style.bottom = "0";
          video.style.right = "0";
          video.style.zIndex = "9999";
          document.body.appendChild(video);
    })
}
});
```